# Is it possible to have an in-line if statement with membership in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, membership

I'm trying to build up a banded matrix with 9 components to solve a finite difference problem. My idea is to have them first in a normal matrix and then diagonalised it with some sort of scipy.sparse method.

My code works fine with a normal if condition like:

```py
for l,c in enumerate(node_n):
    Pxx[l,4] = epsi
    if (c[0]+1,c[1]) in tensor:
        Pxx[l,5] = psi
```

but I was wondering it is instead possible to write it in a single line like:

```py
Pxx[l,2] = gamma if ((c[0]+1,c[1]+1) in tensor)
```

I've tried with and without brackets, using square brackets and so on but I always get `invalid syntax`. I know it's not a big problem but I would rather have 9 lines of code, one for each component, instead of 9 if statements.

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: An inline `if` always needs an `else`.

Comment: `Pxx[l,2] = gamma if ((c[0]+1,c[1]+1) in tensor) else Pxx[l,2] ` could be an option (depending on the rest of your code)

Comment: I mean you _can_ do `if (c[0]+1,c[1]) in tensor: Pxx[l,5] = psi` in one line (though I would usually not recommend it).

Comment: Oh thank you very much @DanielRoseman, that's what I was afraid of. And thank you everybody for your answers!